# Grant admin consent for service principal

Tags: azure, authorization, microsoft-graph-api

I am the owner of my subscription, and I have a service principal that needs to access the Microsoft Graph API with the below permissions:
[image]

evidence as owner:
[image]

What steps do I take to permit consent for the service principal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be admin of the tenant linked to the subscription, not the subscription itself. If you were, the first screen would have a link you can click to provide admin consent to the scopes defined on that page.

Comment: Specifically, Global Admin role is required to consent those permissions. MS Graph API admin consent requires Global Admin, while others can be consented by Application Admins and Cloud Application Admins.